# Помогите разобратся с Gulp

Tags: gulp

Есть у меня Gulpfile.js.
Вставляю код.

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
      concat = require('gulp-concat');
      minify = require('gulp-minify');


gulp.task('concat', function() {
  return gulp.src('./js/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});


gulp.task('minify', async function () {
  gulp.src('./dist/all.js') 
  .pipe(minify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/all-min.js'));
});
```

После команды в консоли gulp concat и gulp minify все работает.
Скажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы можно было сделать так чтобы просто после запуска gulp команды работали по очереди.
Думаю как прописать строку типо

gulp.task('default', ['concat', 'minify'])

Но такая строка не работает

Еще начал смотреть в документации так вообще запуск функций по другому

```js
const { task } = require('gulp');

function build(cb) {
  // body omitted
  cb();
}

task(build);
```

Кто в теме обьясните зачем усложнять жизнь такими function build(cb) и что это значит.

И как сделать чтобы tasks запускали один за другим по очереди.

Кстати версия gulp у меня, я так понимаю последняя 
CLI version: 2.2.0
Local version: 4.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gulp.task('default', ['concat', 'minify']);
```

Задача `default` запускает задачи `concat` и `minify` параллельно, а требуется последовательно. Вначале отработать должна `concat` и только после - `minify`

Решить последовательный запуск задач можно с помощью [gulp-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sequence):

```
...

var gulpsequence = require('gulp-sequence');

gulp.task('default', gulpsequence(['concat', 'minify']));
```

Если есть независимые друг от друга задачи (например task1 и task2), то их можно запускать параллельно, на определенном шаге, в рамках последовательного выполнения задач:

```
gulp.task('default', gulpsequence(['concat', ['task1', 'task2'], 'minify']));
```

Здесь вначале выполняется `concat`, затем `task1` и `task2` - параллельно, а после - `minify`