# Последовательное выполнение задач

Tags: javascript, gulp

Есть две Gulp задачи. Когда я пытаюсь ввести предвыполнение pug:data перед pug,  выполняется только pug:data. Где ошибся, как исправить? Без gulp.series pug полностью рабочая задача.

```
 gulp.task('pug:data', function() {
        return gulp.src('src/data/**/*.json')
            .pipe(merge({
                fileName: 'data.json',
                edit: (json, file) => {
                    var filename = nodePath.basename(file.path),
                        primaryKey = filename.replace(nodePath.extname(filename), ''),
                        data = {};

                    data[primaryKey] = json;
                    return data;
                }
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('temp'));
    });

    gulp.task('pug', gulp.series('pug:data'), function buildHTML() {
        return gulp.src(path.src.pug)
            .pipe(pug({
                pretty: true,
                data: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('temp/data.json'))
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html))
            .pipe(browserSync.stream())
    });
```

Comment: Можно еще использовать пакет `gulp_sequence`. Мой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1012927/327441) на похожий вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение, в gulp 4 тело кода таска должно передаваться в функцию вместе с зависимостями. Рабочий код выглядит так:

```
gulp.task('pug', gulp.series('pug:data', function buildHTML() {
            return gulp.src(path.src.pug)
                .pipe(pug({
                    pretty: true,
                    data: JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('temp/data.json'))
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html))
                .pipe(browserSync.stream())
}));
```